# Accessing a collection of an entity with jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a simple 'chapter' model:

```
class Chapter(db.Model):
    book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book, collection_name='chapters')
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    father = db.SelfReferenceProperty(collection_name='sons')
```

And I'm trying to list the chapters and the sub chapters on a HTML page with:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for chap in chaps %}
       Title: {{ chap.title}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

With this i get all the chapters and sub chapters, but i want to list the sub chapters of the chapters, so, I tried this:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for chap in chaps %}
       Title: {{ chap.title}}<br>
       {% for sub in chap.sons %}
         teste: {{ sub.title }}<br>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But looks like chap.sons don't have anything because it doesn't show anything, however i don't get any errors.

(I'm sure that i have 'sons' on the database)

How do i use the 'collection_name' properly?

Comment: Do you have fathers saved? Are you sure?

Comment: yap, they are in the database viewer

Comment: If you do the same for a book like: `{% for chap in book.chapters  %}
       Title: {{ chap.title}}<br>
       {% for sub in chap.sons %}
         teste: {{ sub.title }}<br>
       {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: like that it even stops showing the chapters

Comment: Could you please try to change variable name sub to something (for example sub_chap) else and report back?

Comment: check you logic by dumping your code into http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/admin/interactive

Comment: Having same problem - did you ever find a solution or is this a known limitation of jinja2?

Comment: At the time of this post i was using "DB", but i changed to "NDB", because collections weren't doing what i needed